# Why am I getting a TIMEOUT error, or an exception handler error?

Tags: c#, loops, exception, ping

When I run this program it is suppose to ping each website 4 times and save the results (website and return time in milliseconds) in a .csv file. But I'm getting an exception handler or a timeout error. Can someone please help me?
Here is what I have:

```
using System;
using System.Collection.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Text;
using Threading.Teask;

namespace PingApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<string> lstWebSites = new List<string>();
            lstWebSites.Add("www.yahoo.com");
            lstWebSites.Add("www.att.com");
            lstWebSites.Add("www.verizon");
            string filename = @"PingLog.csv";
            {
                using (var writer = new StreamWriter(filename, true)) 
                {
                    foreach(string website in lstWebSites)
                    {
                        writer.WriteLine(website, lstWebSites);
                        try
                        {
                            Ping myPing = new Ping();
                            PingReply reply = myPing.Send(website, 1000);
                            if (reply != null)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", reply.Address, reply.RoundtripTime);
                            }
                        }                   
                        catch
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine.("ERROR: You have some TIMEOUT issue");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can share the full exeption please

Comment: well in the current code I get TIMEOUT issue, but if I make any changes then I get PingException was unhandled. And it underlines the PingReply reply = myPing.Send(website, 1000);

Comment: Do you think maybe I have my code in the wrong order? Please help me.

Comment: Until you share the full exception details, we can't help

Comment: When I run it, it is saving the URL to the .csv file but it will not save the results from the ping... HELP.

Comment: It doesn't save the results from the ping because of this line of code writer.WriteLine(website, lstWebSites);

Comment: So then what should I put in place of lstWebSites?

Comment: I have added the answer in the end

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What have you tried and what was the result? As you did in school... please show your work. :) It's part of the process of getting questions answered on SO. It's helpful to you because it forces you to investigate your own problem and think it through. It also proves to readers that you did your homework and made a reasonable attempt to answer your own question. Thirdly, it helps readers find and diagnose the problem resulting in a better answer for you and less time wasted for us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I have done some changes to the code. I deleted

```
writer.WriteLine(website, lstWebSites);
```

and added

```
writer.WriteLine(website + "," + reply.Address.ToString() + "," + reply.RoundtripTime);
```

in the place of `Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", reply.Address, reply.RoundtripTime);`
now the result is looks like

[image]

It does pinging only one time foreach site.

Answer (score 1):

```
lstWebSites.Add("www.verizon");
```

would timeout.  I think you want

```
lstWebSites.Add("www.verizon.com");
```

Comment: Sorry about that, that was my typo. I don't have that in my code.

Comment: I put your code in application and it worked, only verizon gave the timeout exception

Comment: Its pinging each website 4 times and saving to a .csv file?

Comment: www.yahoo.com
www.att.com
www.verizon
www.yahoo.com
www.att.com
www.verizon
www.yahoo.com
www.att.com
www.verizon.com
www.yahoo.com
www.att.com
www.verizon.com
this is the csv file, I haven't seen your comment, I'll look now why it doesn't show ping results

Comment: When I run it, it is saving the websites but not the ping results

Comment: I also need to add for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) which should ping each website 4 times, where should I add that without getting ant errors?

Comment: You can put it just outside the foreach loop or inside depending on how you want to iterate (abcabcabc vs aaabbbccc, respectively).

Comment: That worked, thanks so much. Now I just need to be able to save my results into the .csv file also. just a little more help.

Comment: Thanks :) it is saving the results in the csv file :) I showed you the picture of a csv file,

Comment: Do you know how I can get it to save in a single string line, for example: www.yahoo.com first ping, second ping, third ping, fourth ping then the next website and so on....

Comment: foreach (string website in lstWebSites) after this loop add for(var i =1; i<=4; i++) loop to do pinging 4 times, add all the answers to one string and you'll get the answer

Comment: no, thats still not it. I need it to where all four pings are in a line separated by comma's

Comment: Change WriteLine to Write ending with a comma then add an empty WriteLine() after the four iterations.